# Custom drush command not being loaded

Tags: drush

I'm creating a custom drush command in my module but it's not being seen. Wondering if someone would know why. The module is enabled. It seems the hook_drush_command() is never being called for my module, but I see it being done for other modules. I've tried clearing cache.

bir.drush.inc is located in /bir/drush directory

```
function bir_drush_command() {
  $items = array();

  $items['bir-process-images'] = array(
      'description' => dt('Process images on image server.'),
      'aliases' => array('birpi'),
      'arguments' => array(
          'days' => dt('Number of day(s) in the past to begin processing.'),
          'nids' => dt('Comma separated list of node ids to process.'),
      ),
      'required-arguments' => array(1),
      'options' => array(
          'days' => dt('Number of day(s) in the past to begin processing.'),
          'nids' => dt('Comma separated list of node ids to process.'),
      ),
      'examples' => array(
          'drush bir-process-images --days=7' => dt('Process images from 7 days ago to now.'),
          'drush bir-process-images --nids="2409,2309,5896"' => dt('Process images for given node ids.'),
          'drush birpi --days=7' => dt('Process images from 7 days ago to now.'),
          'drush birpi --nids="2409,2309,5896"' => dt('Process images for given node ids.'),
      ),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

When I type $ drush help at the command line, my command is never shown. I tried printing out the $items array in the function and it never even gets there. If I print $items out in another module, for example search_api, it prints to my screen. So, for some reason it's simply not picking up that I'm calling the hook in my file. Or, not seeing the file?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you put the drush.inc file in the root of your module folder? I don't think Drush will automatically traverse sub-folders in a module to look for an include file

Comment: @Clive - Yes. That is where I had it at first. Then I looked at some other modules and they had it in a drush folder. So tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Even though I closed the command line window, I never cleared the drush cache. Running "$ drush cache-clear drush" fixed the issue.

Comment: That would do it! You can also use the alias `drush cc drush` to save time.